# How do I have the choice made in an in-cell drop down menu affect the cells next to it?

Tags: google-sheets, contacts, data-validation

I have a contact sheet with names going down the list and contact info in the cells to the right of each name.

On a separate signup sheet, I used data validation to create a drop down menu with the names from the contact sheet as options.

Next, I would like to set it up so that someone choosing one of these names automatically fills in the appropriate contact information in the neighboring cells.

Is this possible?

If I can do it but have to use a different method than the data validation, that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use =vlookup. Say your names are in ColumnA of Sheet1, with corresponding details in ColumnsB:C. In a different sheet ColumnD (assumed to be where the validation takes place) with names can be matched with the corresponding details with a formula such as:

```
=VLOOKUP($D1,Sheet1!$A:$C,2,false)
```

copied across to the right (with `2` there changed to `3`) and then both formulae copied down to suit.